# Yii2 include from vendor directory

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have yii2 basic version. I want to use Yii2 GridView. Using [docs](http://demos.krajee.com/grid) I 've installed and updated it. Now I can see directory in directory `/basic/vendor` directory `./kartik-v` I changed it to `./kartik` and it's subdirectory `yii2-grid` to `grid`
Now it's said to include module in config.
I go to standard path: `/config/web.php`
and add this block as part of config:

```
'modules' => [
   'gridview' =>  [
        'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module'
        // enter optional module parameters below - only if you need to  
        // use your own export download action or custom translation 
        // message source
        // 'downloadAction' => 'gridview/export/download',
        // 'i18n' => []
    ]
],
```

How can I use it in view, for example, now?
This is code of my view and it says that it can't find it there.

```
    use app\vendor\kartik\grid\GridView;
    $dataProvider = null;
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        'name',
        'created_at:datetime',
    ],
]) ;
```

Need some help.
**UPD1**
Thanks to Tim Ogilvy I understand that I should use namespace to get it and it's not necessary to add in in config/php . Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Did you install it using composer? If so, composer should be bringing it in as a library.  Also your use statement is referencing a file path, rather than a namespace. You may need to read about namespaces and class autoloading to understand what is happening here.

Comment: Yes, as composer. Ok, gonna read some. To get it in view I should somehow use namespace, I see.

Comment: > If so, composer should be bringing it in as a library.
Don't understand, I shouldn't add modules in config/web.php?

Comment: Where does composer put dependency?

Comment: Does Yii load composer's autoload.php?  It probably does - in which case you should be able to refer to the class via it's namespace ie `\kartik\grid\GridView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a read of [the Yii Manual for autoloading](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html).

It explains a couple of different ways to load classes, including using `/vendor/autoload.php` which is the composer autoloader.

Either way, once you have the autoloader set up correctly, you should be able to refer to the gridview via it's vendor namespace as visible [in the gridview documentation](http://demos.krajee.com/grid#gridview).

**Example taken from the Table Styling section:**

```
use kartik\grid\GridView;

// Generate a bootstrap responsive striped table with row highlighted on hover
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
    'responsive'=>true,
    'hover'=>true
]);
```

Note that the `use` statement uses *back slashes* rather than *forward slashes*.

For windows users, it's not immediately apparent that this is not a path, however linux and mac users are immediately able to identify that this refers to a namespace, and not a path.

Comment: Thanx, I'll read it and when I solve my issue, I'll approve answer.